# R - Converting a CSV file from Unicode to Windows-1252

Tags: r, unicode, encoding, windows-1252

I wish to read a CSV file in R that I have downloaded from GCS in the Unicode format.

When I try to read the file it goes like this :

> **Warning message: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :   invalid input found on input connection 'reviews_report_201605.csv'**

The data is read till line 39 where it encounters a special character and cannot read any further :

> 2 basic features in non logged in sections are not working.
>   ,2016-05-03T09:52:06Z,1462269126290

The code truncates when it reaches that smiley face. I do not mind reading the smiley face as question marks either.

My workaround was to save the CSV through a notepad as an ANSI file which converted the same the same smiley to ??.

How do I do this in R? I have tried multiple methods but none of them work, and it is not manually doable as there are a lot of files.

The code I applied as the file was in Unicode was as follows :

```
reviews1 <- read.csv("reviews_report_201605.csv", header = T,stringsAsFactors = F,fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE")
```

Please do suggest any ideas as to how to resolve this.

Comment: If you downloaded it from the Internet, it would probably have been in UTF-8, not UTF-16. Try that as the fileEncoding arg.

Comment: `` _Persevering Face_ (Unicode `U+1F623` (or surrogate pair `0xd83d`,`0xde23`))  **is not defined in _Windows-1252_** so it appears like replacement characters `??` if saved using Notepad.